# how to filter data in different models in django?

Tags: django, filtering

my models

```
class Player(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    company_id = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path_id_card, null=True, 
    max_length=255)
    company_id_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='player', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this is my model , how to filter data in multiple model?

Comment: Have you this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/ from the official Django documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Queryset to [filter by modal object's field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

You can use this to also filter [relationships on models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

In your example, you can do a filter of all the Player entries that have a Character that have Weapon with strength > 10
`Player.objects.filter(character__weapon__strength__gt=10)`

You can also separate them out into 3 variables for readability purposes.

```
player_q = Player.objects.filter(character__isnull=False)
ch_q = player_q.filter(weapon__isnull=False)
wpn_dmg = ch_q.filter(strength__gt=10)
```

Please note that filters are lazy and thus don't return actual model instances [untill they're evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). I think in this case gt returns an instance.

[This documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) goes over all the fieldset lookups you can do with QuerySet object methods `filter(), get(),` and `exclude()`

Comment: No actually i have 3 models and want to filter the data in single page

Comment: @dilja Are you trying to combine 3 different model records, i.e `Author, Post and Website` to pass as context or are you trying to create foreign key relationships with 3 different models?

Comment: forien key relation ship

Comment: 3 different models , how can i use django filter?

Comment: @dilja I've updated my answer. Please make sure to look into database relationship management on my second link.